# Securing all edges of an area

Tags: geometry

Well, I, as the King of the World, have built the great Tower of Me!!! However, because everyone seems to hate me for some reason, citizens keep trying to enter my tower to kill me. So, I have assigned some laser transmitters in my castle. However, as the technology is new, a laser transmitter can only cover the edge of one tower. An edge of a tower is protected by having at least one transmitter at the end of its vertices. This is my castle at the moment:

[image: Laser Castle]

Sorry for my bad drawingBlack rectangles represent towers. Red dots represent transmitters. Orange lines represent laser-protected edges. Purple lines represent unprotected edges.

However, I have been faced with a few problems:

a) My adviser thinks I can protect the castle with only 5 transmitters. I understand that a transmitter will have to protect at least 3 edges, but how can this be done?

Good News! My castle now has 9 towers, in a 3*3 arrangement!

[image: 3*3 Castle]

b) After working with my advisers for many hours, we found we couldn't use just 5 transmitters to cover this up. So, how do we protect it with 6?

c) However, is 6 really the minimum amount of transmitters needed? Could we use more?

Sorry for my bad drawingGreater News! My castle is now in a 3*4 arrangement, with 3 new towers!

[image: 3*4 Castle]

d) However, we've only got 8 more transmitters. So, is it possible to cover this whole area up, and how? If we can't cover them all, what is the maximum amount of towers that can be protected?

Please answer there questions in a 9th-10th grade intelligence level, as I don't understand some concepts in maths.

(Sorry for my bad drawings)

Comment: In the first diagram, shouldn't the line extending left from the top transmitter be colored in as protected?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes sorry didn't know that happened.